# Python Script to run a C Program

Tags: python, c++, c, scripting

I have a C/C++ program which takes a set of arguments and displays a set of outputs to a command line (for my research).

I would like to write a Python script to run this program multiple times for different inputs and write outputs to a file. I am planning to run the program with exhaustive inputs.

However, I don't have any experience in writing scripts or programming in Python. So, I was wondering if I could get some pointers where to start.

As an example, I would like to write a script for doing:

```
./program -flag1 [val1] -flag2 [val2] -arg1 -arg2 -arg3 ...
Append the output to Output.txt
./program -flag1 [val1] -flag2 [val2] -arg1 -arg2 -arg4 ...
Append the output to Output.txt
./program -flag1 [val1] -flag2 [val2] -arg1 -arg2 -arg5 ...
Append the output to Output.txt
...
...
./program -flag1 [val1] -flag2 [val2] -arg1000 -arg1000 -arg1000 ...
Append the output to Output.txt
```

**EDIT**: I am running the program on Linux through command line, bash.

**EDIT2 SLN**: Just for a future reference to others who might be a beginner, doing something similar, the solution looks like following. I stripped all the parts that only affects my case.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for commands in listArgs:

    # Build command through for loop in listArgs.
    # Details are omitted.
    cmd = ["./program", "-flag1", "val1", "-flag2", "val2", "-arg1", "-arg2", ... ]

    # Open/Create the output file
    outFile = open('/path/to/file/Output.txt', 'a+')

    result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = result.stdout.read()

    outFile.write(out)
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Python's subprocess would probably do the trick nicely . . . With that said, a tool like `bash` is probably more suited to this task.

Comment: What platform?  Windows?  Mac?  Linux?

Comment: "I have a C/C++ program..." No, you don't. It's one or the other, unless you have a C++ program in which one or more of your compilation units are in C and you have taken the requisite care to make them work together properly, which is often non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently recommended way of running and controlling executables using Python is **subprocess** module. You can use different arguments, capture stdout, process it, or just redirect to arbitrary file. Have a look at documentation here https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use python to execute commands through the terminal. For example

```
import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")
```

This will execute the terminal command `>> echo 'hello world'`